# How can I make a custom mob that looks like the Enderman?

Tags: minecraft-modding

I have previously made two other mods that added in mobs. In order for the mob to look like a wolf, I needed the wolf.java file (Found online).

Without setting a defined java file, the mob will use the villager's java file, which can lead to some messed up mobs.

Now, I have a requirement that a mob looks like the Enderman; how would I achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about the skin? Or the AI for the creature?

Comment: I mean like the model. The java file makes it so that creepers look one way and endermen look one way

Comment: Code for the game is stored in .class files, so I assume you're talking about the model for the skin. I edited your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Nik3141 What class file would the enderman's model be in?

Comment: It wouldn't. .class files contain code which runs the game. Give me a couple minutes and I can try to figure out where to extract the model. In the meanwhile, do you have windows, mac, or linux, and what version are you  on?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and playing on 1.12.2

Comment: So just a disclaimer this needs 7zip so you may want to start downloading that now.

Comment: i have it installed

Comment: Your question from Arqade has been migrated here. I have adapted it a bit so that we get better and more interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft does not support remodeling entities yet, therefore the Vanilla datapack also does not contain entity models. Where you would find the specifics of entity models is in the code.

Comment: So by remodeling do you mean changing the hitbox for it? And when you say "yet" does that mean you know that it is going to become a thing?

Comment: With "model" I hopefully mean the same as the asker. And with "yet" I mean that they added more and more features to resource packs over time, including block models and item models. Entity models will surely come one day.

Comment: Oh so you can give entities a custom hitbox and texture? Isn't that already implemented in the Asphodel Meadows datapack? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k03W9Qkag3M

Comment: No, you can not, that's the point of my answer. I quickly jumped through that video and saw nothing like that either. If there is something like that, it's probably done with blocks.

Comment: Oh sorry I rewatched and it isn't in that video. The creator added retextured pigmen with guardians riding them that had a model that is slanted, very unlike the default model and texture. It should be at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyBybQbDZaI&t=657s

Comment: Those could be armour stands.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft stores skins for all creatures in Minecraft as .png files.

These can be found in the [.Minecraft](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/.minecraft) folder, under the "resourcepacks" sub folder. You can open each one with a program like WinZip, 7Zip, WinRAR, etc. You can also find this folder by opening the Minecraft launcher, choosing "Resource Packs" the "Open Resource Pack Folder".

The [contents](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Resource_pack#Contents) of each holds a file for each and every texture in the game, including the textures, or "skins" for each mob in the game. The enderman skin can be found under

> `<resourcepack.zip>\textures\entity\enderman\`

However, if you're looking to change the actual model of the mob, this can only be found in the Vanilla Resource pack. The [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Changing_Minecraft_entity_models#Getting_Started) has a tutorial for Editing these.

Comment: That is the textures, not the models

Comment: Sorry didn't see your answer before I put mine.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to your files app or just your windows search bar and type in %appdata%. In this folder, go to .minecraft, which is your minecraft directory. Go to your versions folder and select your  version, and then in that folder right click the .jar file. Use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the files, and then go inside to the assets folder. Navigate through the folders until your filepath looks like this (example for 1.14.3, it will look *slightly* different for other versions):

`AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.14.3\1.14.3\assets\minecraft\textures\entity`.

This should be where you can find all of the entities. All of the textures for the entire game are around this file too, so if you want the dirt or golden sword texture they aren't far away either.

Comment: that is textures, not models

Comment: Oh like the dimensions of the hitbox?

Comment: Yeah, i need the .java file of the enderman

Comment: So what does this .java file do? Does it render the enderman, give him AI...

Comment: I think it provides the shape of it? prob renders it

Comment: So if you  go to that folder with the assets folder in it, and look down at the long list of .class files...it's one of those

Comment: There are no CLASS files in my assets folder

Comment: One folder up from assets